# Redis , redis-cli and search and query failing with @ I wonder why

Tags: redis

I have been trying to make a query with redis-cli and not only and been failing for hours.

```
FT.SEARCH idx:user @email:pop@gmail.com LIMIT 0 10
```

It's always about the second @ and I cannot solve it.

If you have encountered that issue before, thank for helping me past it.

PS: Of course I have tried "" '' ' to no avail ...

PS: Of course I have tried "" '' ' to no avail ...

I want it to work !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the '@' in the email address. The parser thinks it's for a new field named. You'll probably need to escape the '.' as well:

```
FT.SEARCH idx:user @email:pop\@gmail\.com LIMIT 0 10
```